# Can I install Ubuntu without DVD, USB or doing a dual install?

Tags: system-installation

I have quite an old PC and wanted to install Ubuntu to replace XP. However, the DVD drive is getting old and does not recognize any DVDRs I burn to install Ubuntu. I can't install off USB (even with Plop) and the only other way I have found was a dual install but that was too slow and I was told if I deleted windows, it would take Ubuntu with it

Comment: "dual install" no what that is is a WUBI install (linux inside windows) and yes it is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dvd drive can at lesat read CDs - use Minimal installer: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can install over the network. You will need another computer with Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Alas, I have no other computer with Ubuntu but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minimal install which will fit on a cd and it will then download the required extra software.  [Minimal Install page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PC_.28x86.29)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The Op says that his DVD R/W does not recognise cd/dvd

Comment: The op actually said that that DVDRs were not recognized, not CDs.  The op also mentions trying to use Plop with no success.  This suggests that the op's drive will read cds since Plop is usually booted from a cd (however it can be used with a floppy).  @Patil Aditya

Comment: thank you, this worked for me. You are quite correct, my drive was refusing to recognise DVDRs (still recognises normally DVDs). Thanks to your suggestion, I had an easy install and am now running Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There are two ugly methods you can use to install Ubuntu on your system. But I'll say you should install xubuntu to avoid having a sluggish system after doing all the mess.

1. **Netboot**
   In netboot, what you do is download files over internet(preferably high speed ethernet) and install the OS on your system.

   The detailed instructions on using netboot are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot).
2. **Using other system**
   In case you are unable to use netboot(difficulty, slow internet, errors etc) you can use this method to install Ubuntu on your HDD.

   - First, get access to another computer which has ability to either use a external HDD or attach a slave drive in it.
   - All you have to do is that connect your HDD to this computer either externally or as slave, and then use DVD/USB to install Ubuntu on this drive.
   - Now connect your drive back on your computer as master, set it as priority boot in BIOS and you are ready to go.

Comment: I used the Minimal Install option which downloaded most of the OS off the internet. I presume that is the same as Netboot? Thanks for helping

Comment: @YorkshireNed There is some difference. Netboot downloads everything from Internet in a go.Minimal CD uses a small ISO which one can use to download whatever software you want.